# Why don't more demon spawn exist?

Tags: supernatural

In supernatural, season 5, episode 6 we find out about a demon spawn. Half-demon, half-human all-powerful.

So why don't more of these exist? Is this something difficult on the behalf of demons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The rarity of the cambion or Antichrist is probably attributed best to a difficulty in making one, trust factors for who would be allowed to have access to such a powerful and dangerous weapon and the undue attention, such a being would bring upon itself from the Angelic Host. The best thing Demons could do is to keep their weapon hidden and ignorant, but well groomed and poised for operation.**

The best way to answer that is to consider the numbers. We have seen Demons and possessed humans in significant numbers in any particular episode. We have seen half a dozen die in any particular fight scene. Judging from that, there must be plenty of low-quality foot soldier demons available in their fight against humans.

Normal untrained and unaware humans are no threat to Demons. When things get hairy or when skilled Hunters are involved, more senior demons may be forced to come into the field and when in doubt Crowley, King of the Crossroad Demons may enter the fray. Given the rarity and power profile, an Antichrist must be an escalation in the war between Heaven and Hell.

First appearing in Season 5, [The Children Are The Future](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/I_Believe_the_Children_Are_Our_Future) Jesse Turner is the first and only Antichrist known and is unaware of his supernatural stature or abilities.

> According to Castiel, Jesse is an Antichrist, also known as "cambion" or "katako". Contrary to common definition, he is not the son of Lucifer; he's just a form of demon spawn, born from a human woman—a virgin—impregnated by the demon which was possessing her. (The mechanics of this are not gone into in detail apart from natural labor and birth-giving.) He explains to them that the chaos Jesse has been causing is nothing compared to what it could be if he were to get angry. He then reveals that as the Antichrist, Jesse is destined to align with Lucifer and, "with a word", destroy the Heavenly Host.

**We have only seen one "cambion" or Antichrist in the entire series. There may be a number of reasons for this:**

- Judging from the power of the cambion/Antichrist, it would make sense, only a trusted agent would be allowed to make one, since having access to one might give the handler an undue advantage. Since trust is something demons have in short supply, it may be as simple as NO ONE IS TRUSTED ENOUGH TO MAKE ONE.
- The process required to make them is either very difficult (requires a virgin girl to be possessed by a demon. That doesn't seem very difficult.) or requires a unique series of events to create one.
- They are only able to be made under a particular circumstance (The seventh son of a seventh son, only when the moon is in Aquarius, when Jupiter aligns with Mars). This would be much more rare and would explain why there would be far fewer of them.
- They may require a particular type of demon, virgin, ritual, condition (a prophecy of Lucifer being released from hell). With significant variables, the possibility of success is decreased and the bulk of the time is spent making sure the event has optimal opportunities for success.
- One of the most likely reasons is the attention such a creature might bring upon itself if it were revealed before it was ready. While it is incredibly powerful, a successful [Alpha Strike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_strike_%28gaming%29) by a group of Angels could make short work of such a creature if they could be sure of its identity. Jesse's powers have been outlined as:

> Jesse is half-demon, half-human, but far more powerful than either, according to Castiel. He is literally being one of the most powerful entities Sam and Dean have ever encountered. Lucifer's presence on Earth magnifies his powers to extreme levels.
>
> - Stealth/Cloaking - Through his power, he's kept hidden from both angels or demons unless he wants to be.
> - Exorcism - Jesse was able to exorcise a demon from his birth mother Julia with a simple "get out of her".
> - Teleportation - According to Castiel, he can teleport anywhere on Earth at a thought. When Jesse went upstairs to "say goodbye to his parents", he vanished and Sam and Dean have not seen him since.
> - Terrakinesis - Can create a minor earthquake when angry.
> - Omnipotence - As nigh omnipotent, Jesse is able to achieve basically anything through thought or iteration. He grows in strength exponentially with Lucifer risen. As Castiel puts it, "with a word", Jesse can destroy the Host of Heaven.
> - Reality Altering - Jesse can warp reality, being able to make such things like fantasy/urban myth be true, and put it back just as easily.
> - Conjuring - Jesse can create things, as simply as by believing in them.
>
> Despite these tremendous powers, Jesse is still vulnerable to things like Ruby's Knife, as evidenced by the fact that Castiel tries to kill him using the knife. Also, now that Lucifer has been re-imprisoned in his Cage, Jesse's powers may have diminished.

Given the scale of such powers, it makes sense there should be a very limited numbers of such powerful creatures. Who could control them without the influence of Lucifer or other powerful angels/demons like him.

Answer (score 1):

Within the Supernatural universe, it's really quite simple:

- Throughout seasons 4 and 5, the angels reference God's plan numerous times.
- The outline of God's plan is occasionally mentioned - it goes up to the Apocalypse, but not beyond it.
- The Antichrist is part of the plan.  No antichrist would come about until the time of the apocalypse.
- We're "off the script" now, so even more antichrists could be born.  However, they don't have accelerated growth - they're babies, and won't grow into their powers for years to come.

Comment: Sorry god's plan is 'one anti-christ per apocalypse'?

Comment: @Pureferret Don't know about that, but what I intended to say was "No antichrist until (just before?) the apocalypse" - although the kid was referred to as an antichrist, he hadn't yet grown into the role.  It could be more that are around his age exist, and it's just coincidence he was found first.  But I highly doubt any older antichrists/demon-children exist.

Comment: I think my phone autocorrected So->sorry. But that's fair enough. I'd imagine we'd see more though if they existed.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, Jesse is the only half-human/half-demon of the Supernatural world. The reasons for him being the only one can be as I see them:**

1) Jesse was powerful, "And with a word he can destroy the host of heaven", but he only has his powers while Lucifer walks the Earth.

2) Jesse's mortal mother was a virgin. Whether that plays a part in the Cambion's creation I'm not sure but that's generally how these things go.

3) The demon who resided in Jesse's mother revealed demonic secrets through memory, which is how she learned salt would hurt it and forced it out. It could be dangerous if too many demons did that.

4) Once the child is born it must be constantly watched over because the child would have a ward that would shield it from detection from Angels & Demons.